# Is there any custom builder for BootSwatch the remove unnecessary selectors?

Tags: css, performance, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I'm using BootSwatch's Flatly theme and happy about the look and feel of that. However, the main CSS theme contains too much redundant selectors that ended up bloat up my Site.

Bootstrap has a custom builder that helps developers to choose what they want. Is there any similar tool for BootSwatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less files for the flatly theme is available at https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/tree/gh-pages/flatly > bootswatch.less.

The sections are clearly labelled - you can exclude the sections you don't need, pick up the Bootstrap less source and compile it to CSS.

Note - you can use http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and the generated config.json file to help figure out the less files for different components.